# Second Order Homogenous ODE solve with Real Analysis Integration topics

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question**:
Suppose that $u\in C([a,b])$ is twice continuously differentiable, $V\in C([a,b])$, $V(x)\geq0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and
$$
-u''(x) + V(x)u(x)=0, \;\; x\in [a,b],
$$
$$
u(a)=u(b)=0
$$
Prove that $u(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

**Note**: I'm in a Real Analysis class and this question belongs to the Integration topics (fundamental theorem of calculus, integration by parts, change of variables, etc) also they haven't taught anything about ODE, but I know it is a Second order homogenous ODE because I took Calculus.